# fulltext search PHP

Tags: mysql, search, full-text-search

I am trying to do the following serach

As You will be able to see I am fullsearching a number of different rows from different tables.

```
SELECT *, 
  group_concat(offer ORDER BY offer_value DESC SEPARATOR ',') as offers, 
  group_concat(offer_value ORDER BY offer_value DESC) as offer_value, 
  MATCH (approved_business.tradingname,business_stores.suburb) AGAINST ('lol') AS score 
FROM approved_business, business_stores, Real_Cash_Offers 
WHERE approved_business.id = business_stores.business_id 
  AND Real_Cash_Offers.business_id = approved_business.id 
  AND Real_Cash_Offers.storeid = business_stores.storeid 
  AND MATCH (approved_business.tradingname,business_stores.suburb) AGAINST ('lol') 
GROUP BY id ORDER BY offer_value DESC
```

The issue I am having is the following

> Incorrect arguments to MATCH

Comment: @adlawson: Your personal opinion on MySQL is irrelevant and non-constructive in this post. He wants to use MySQL, and it can do it well when configured properly. Answering a question like this is not helping at all and is condescending. Please don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

All columns in `MATCH (...)` must be from the same table.